# Is using too many partial views a bad practice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, partial-views

I am very new to MVC design paradigm and I am laying out my first MVC Application which has a Grid full of employees and as soon as you click on each employee on the grid it loads more details about the employee in the Tab control below.

Tab control has three tabs and each represent different aspect of employee information.

Now, I have a different model for List which goes to Grid and then separate models/partial View combination for each tab in the tab control.

I did go for this design for a couple of reasons:

1. Separation  of concerns : HTML page design is also like class design and if each HTML piece is on different partial view then the code is more manageable and cleaner.
2. Model Binding is much easier: I can map each partial view to one model  and that Model/partial view combo can be loaded and re-loaded without having to worry about other parts on the page.

I think this is very clean and I like it. However, I am not too sure how far or how much aligned I am to best MVC design practices. Is it good a bad design OR it is just a matter of preference. Are there any downsides of doing it this way?

Comment: That sounds fine.  One of the nice things about using asp.net is that using partials doesn't significantly impact the render time of a page, unlike Ruby on Rails where you take a pretty serious performance hit when rendering partials, especially nested partials.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's great!  Think of these like functions.  When you break out the functionality, you can call it from other views and not have to rewrite the functionality.  It gives each view a logical, coherent purpose to each view.  It keeps your view size down so you're not wading through 100s or 1000s of lines to find what you need.